# Android - MediaPlayer change rotation during/before/on playback?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to record a video using android's camera and want to play that using the android provided media player.

So on/during/before playback can we rotate the video?

Comment: What is the difference between `on playback` and `during playback`?

Comment: And did you mean by `android provided media player` the player app that comes in the device?

Comment: onPlayback is before the display buffer gets images and after playback is after display has images and is going to render on the screen.

Comment: yes android's own media player which is really pain in the ...

Comment: What I know is: when you pass a content (which is your video in our case) to another app, you have no control of it. So my suggestion is to try to rotate the video BEFORE you pass it to the media player. Is there a way to do that? I don't think so.

Comment: I am trying to play it in a SurfaceView and trying to rotate the SurfaceView by 180 so it gives a look that video was rotated! but I am unable to rotate SurfaceView by 180!

Comment: I couldn't find a working example of how you can rotate the video. Regarding the `SurfaceView`, I have no clue how to rotate it|